# Error: XMLHttpRequest error when I try to send an email using SendGrid API, Flutter web and Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, cors, xmlhttprequest, sendgrid

I try ro send email using SendGrid api and flutter web. I use a firebase as a backend but I got this error message.

```
Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
    dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 942:28                get current
packages/http/src/browser_client.dart 81:22                                       <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1661:54                                              runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 147:18                                        handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 784:44                                        handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 813:13                                        _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 575:7                                         [_complete]
dart-sdk/lib/async/stream_pipe.dart 61:11                                         _cancelAndValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/stream.dart 1581:7                                             <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 367:37  _checkAndCall
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 372:39  dcall
dart-sdk/lib/html/dart2js/html_dart2js.dart 37263:58                              <fn>


dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 321:10  createErrorWithStack
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 337:28            _throw
dart-sdk/lib/core/errors.dart 120:5                                           throwWithStackTrace
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1386:11                                          callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                              _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                               _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 177:15           <fn>
```

this is my code

```
import 'package:sendgrid_mailer/sendgrid_mailer.dart';
import 'package:visa_system_admin_pannel/core/constants/constants.dart';
import 'loading_functions.dart';

sendRejectedEmail(
    String emailAddress,
    String name,
    String vid,
    String comment,
    ) async {
  String contentAddress = '''
  تم رفض التأشيرة.
  اسم الزبون
  $name

  رقم الطلب
  $vid
  
  سبب الرفض
  $comment
  
  في حال وجود خطأ ما الرجاء التواصل مع إدارة النظام
  (معلومات التواصل)
  ''';
  final mailer = Mailer(AppConstants.emailAPIKey);
  final toAddress = Address(emailAddress);
  final fromAddress = Address(AppConstants.senderEmail);
  final content = Content('text/plain', contentAddress);
  const subject = 'رفض التأشيرة';
  final personalization = Personalization([toAddress]);

  try{
    final email =
    Email([personalization], fromAddress, subject, content: [content]);
    mailer.send(email).then((result) {
      if (result.isError) {
        errorAlert('خطأ!\n لم يتم إرسال البريد الإلكتروني');
      } else if (result.isValue) {
        successAlert('تم إرسال البريد الإلكتروني بنجاح');
      }
    });
  } catch(e){
    errorAlert('$e');
  }
}
```

My code is working when I disabled the security `'--disable-web-security'` but gives me the same error after deploying to the firebase hosting.

I tryed to enable the CORS headre on my firebase but not working.